# Remove duplicates from array by shifting elements to the end

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I need to write method which takes String[] array as input and returns the given array without duplicates. Using additional array inside method is not allowed, all logic must be done in the input array. All duplicates must be shifted to the end of array and truncated. The template for the method:

```
public String[] remove(String[] array) {
    //Logic is here
    return Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length - numberOfDuplicates)
}
```

Here is what I have done so far. This works for some input, but sometimes it gives incorrect result:

```
public String[] remove(String[] array) {
    int numberOfDuplicates = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1 - numberOfDuplicates; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1 - numberOfDuplicates; j++) {
            if (i != j && array[i].equals(array[j])) {
                String temp = array[array.length - 1 - numberOfDuplicates];
                array[array.length - 1 - numberOfDuplicates] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
                numberOfDuplicates++;
            }
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length - numberOfDuplicates);
}
```

Could you help me with this, please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have an array of length 10, at which index is the last element, what will `length-1-0` be, and so up to where will `i` and `j` go (which are both `<`, not `<=`)? What if `array[i]` equals `temp`? That might not be a problem most of the time, but that's largely because you're checking the same pairs twice and there might be an edge case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When u get match just swap with latest last position. Try with this:

```
public static String[] remove(String[] array) {
    int len = array.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < len && j > 0; j++) {
            if(array[i].equals(array[j])){
                String tmp = array[len -1];
                array[len - 1] = array[j];
                array[j] = tmp;
                len--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(array, len);
}
```

Comment: `j > 0` check is useless

Answer (score 0):

It would be prudent to use **Collections API viz. LinkedHashSet** for the same as below:

```
public static String[] remove(String[] array) {
    return Arrays.copyOf(array, new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array)).size());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, according to the requirement of the task it is not allowed to use any collection api or array inside the method. The given array must be manipulated and returned.